# How to figure out how to wire a 2 wire furnace to 3 wire thermostat

Tags: wiring, furnace

[image][image]

I have a 2 wire furnace and want to wire a 3 wire thermostat. My red wire is connected to the c in the transformer and the white is connected to the load. It works fine 2 wire but I dont want to mess up the new thermostat by having the wires backwards when I add the common to it

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the old wiring system, it doesn't really matter which wire goes to which terminal on the low voltage side of the transformer. Therefore, your installer didn't really care if they mixed up R and C on the transformer.

Which, I think, is exactly what your installer did.  Note that the transformer has an R and C terminal labeled.  Assuming the red wire  goes to the thermostat, that belongs on R.  If the white wire goes to the furnace relays, it belongs on C.

It should be straightforward from there.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands now that wiring doesn't match the convention. It does function, and in that sense it's not "wrong" as-is, but it makes things confusing up at the thermostat end of the wire. So, you could keep the wiring as-is in the furnace and make adjustments at the thermostat, or you could fix the wiring to conform to convention.

### Conform to Convention

The red jumper should go from the transformer R terminal to the single gas valve terminal, ie the one nearer to you when you took the photo. The white jumper should go from the transformer C terminal to one of the distant terminals. The white thermostat wire should go alone on the remaining distant terminal. The red thermostat wire should share R terminal on the transformer with the red jumper and the new common conductor would share the transformer C terminal with the white jumper.

At the thermostat, red would then go to R, white to W, and the new common conductor would go to the common.

### Minimal Change

If you prefer keeping the furnace wiring as-is, connect the new common wire to the transformer C along with the red jumper.

At the thermostat, red would go to W, white would go to R, and the new common conductor would go to the common.

Comment: That's what I was thinking Harper. Thank you both. Very helpful. Really didnt wanna fry the new thermostat the wife got me. Haha.